# Closing question rights in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions

I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474986/open-source-forum); unfortunately someone decided to close it shortly after. I didn't get any answer.

How can someone close my question even if I didn't get an answer or if I wasn't satisfied with it?

Why do people close questions without permission from the owner?

Comment: @Asim: take the time to read the FAQ at http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: What's up with non-native english speakers and question marks??????????????????

Answer (score 3):

In the Stackoverflow FAQ:

> **Why are some questions closed?**
>
> Questions that are deemed sufficiently off-topic may be closed by the community. Users with 3000 reputation can cast a limited number of close votes per day. When a question reaches 5 close votes, it is marked as closed, and will no longer accept answers. Closed questions may be opened by casting reopen votes in the same manner. However, you may only vote to close or reopen a question once.
>
> An explanation of common reasons to close questions is [available on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/describing-close-reasons).

And although your question is still open you may want to reread your question and check it for spelling or grammar mistakes.

In some cases if you appear to be demanding an answer to your question, or for example asking why people aren't answering you, you may get a negative response. All things considered, you still may just have an ol' fashion terrible question that nobody is interested in.

We also don't need your permission to close your question, that's the value in a peer-moderated community.

Make sure you [read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/describing-close-reasons) on meta, and maybe take a look there for your answer.

Comment: Sorry to dig it up but the link is dead

Answer (score 2):

> I have posted my Question and some one has closed that question,

That "some one" is the community; closing questions is a (more or less) democratic process on Stack Overflow.

> but i didn't get my answer from any of the viewer who have view my question or post theire answer,

That's right; closed questions cannot receive answers.

> how can anyone close question when I don't get answer or statisfied with the answer posted against my question???

[nit-picky answer:] By clicking "close". [serious answer:] Your question is against the rules of Stack Overflow and thus not suited to be left open.

> Why people close the question without permission of the question owner ???

There's no need for your permission. When you post a question on SO, you license it under CC-BY-SA and *allow* Stack Overflow to host the content of your question. There is certainly no *obligation* for SO to keep the content alive or even just show it.

Comment: `There is certainly no obligation for SO to keep the content alive or even just show it.`: this is obviously true but it's definitely unrelated with the license. Regardless of the license it's under a question can always be closed or deleted

Comment: @Kop: Right. My point was that posting on SO is nothing more then saying "This post is by me; I give you the right to publish it." and that it is SO's decision whether to actually publish it or not.

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding why your question was off-topic:** Stack Overflow is about programming/developing/etc., and your question (as currently worded) is about choosing an existing program to use on your site, which is more related to system administration.  Before the edit, it was hard to tell what it was asking at all, and that's why you got the "not a real question" close reason.

Compare going to a photographer's studio to ask how he develops film rather than going to get a portrait: the latter is on-topic and relevant for his "purpose", but while the former might be related, it is off-topic.